# Jpa many-to-one unidirectional delete

Tags: hibernate, many-to-one

Let's say we have many-to-one relationship where PostComment contains parent entity Post. There is no cascading here.
My goal is to clean PostComments and I wonder, whether exists the way better than setting PostComment.post = null, persisting entity and then delete PostComment? I use Spring data over JPA\Hibernate, so, JPQL queries and Native queries are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you try something like this?

`em.createQuery("delete from PostComment pc where pc.post = :post") .setParameter("post", postId) .executeUpdate();`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your entity Post and PostComments are managed by hibernate. Clearing the list should make hibernate realize that the comments are removed. You may need to add "orphanRemoval = true" in the @OneToMany annotation in your Post Class.

```
public class Post {
....
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)
private List<PostComment> postComments;
....
}
```

Your Service with removeMethod:

```
@Transactional
public void clearComments() {
    Optional<Post> post = postRepository.findById(1);
    post.get().getPostComments.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had no intention to change relationship model, so , instead of add orphanRemoval I simply delete PostComments in bulk:

```
deleteByIdIn(List<Long> idList);
```

After that step, the same way I clear Parent repo.